# Backup virtual hard disk

Tags: backup, virtual-disk

I have a VM created in VMWare Player. It's VHD is currently sized 17 GB, split among multiple 2 GB files. The host OS is Windows 8. I use CrashPlan in host OS for file backup.

The problem is, whenever I use the VM, CrashPlan detects all parth of VHD as altered and backs up the 17 GB VHD. WHat I want is a software that can run on host OS (Windows 8), treat the VHD as a physical hard disk and create incremental backups of the VHD, includeing all files, programs and the OS

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual machines with physical hard disk partitions. VMware Player will let you configure such VM through its GUI. This way you'll have access to bare files of that VM.

Of course it would be too easy, it won't *just work™*. Such partitions have to be manually unmounted from host before starting VM and remounted after doing so. You can do it in the Disk Management console (`diskmgmt.msc`).

Comment: Well, as Ubuntu's file-system is ext, so just mounting it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using VMWare Player or Workstation, one can easily mount virtual disk (vmdk files). But, as Linux's primary partition's file-system is ext, Windows will not not be able to open the mounted drive as it doesn't support `ext` file-system.

Solution:

You'll need to install a third-party driver which can add support for ext partitions. Doing this on Windows XP or Vista is straightforward, but on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, the available drivers won't work that easily.

Follow the instructions mentioned in this link: http://driesve.tumblr.com/post/1560794187/how-to-mount-an-ext4-drive-in-windows-7

After this, use VMWare Player or workstation to map he vmdk files on Windows host.